# How i can import a file(csv/excel) with partial data to table in database through phpmyadmin?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I needed from my client updated information to fill a clients table.

I exported the table that i wanted to an excel file, and asked them to fill with the new information (it was only a column that i needed updated) and they've sent me back the file.

Now I want to import that information back to my table column.
Trial and error many times, converted to csv the excel file and imported through phpmyadmin.

But it didnt update any column.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

If you just need to generate UPDATE statements from CSV data, you may want to take a look at my FOSS CSV tool, [CSVFix](http://code.google.com/p/csvfix/), which can do this and a lot more without you having to write any code, PHP or otherwise.

Comment: Hi Neil, thanks! i taked a look but its possible to do an update for one column with 1700 rows? It seems to me that i have to do updates row by row..

Comment: It generates one SQL UPDATE for each row in the CSV data file(s) - that's how SQl works, I'm afraid :-)

Comment: @dutraveller, phpMyAdmin would also do the queries row by row, but that doesn't make any difference. SQL is designed to handle hundreds of queries :)

Answer (score 2):

If you have the file in a .csv and you know some PHP, you can just write a script which loops through the file and inserts/updates the records in the database.

For example, lets say that each line in your csv is structured like this:

```
id,name,address,email,date
```

E.g:

```
1,bob smith,344 abc street,test@example.com,2009-04-01
```

You could loop through it in this way:

```
<?php
$data=file_get_contents('your-file.csv');
//Split the file and get an array representing the lines/rows in the .csv
$rows=explode("\n",$data); 

foreach ($rows as $row)
{

   //Remove any excess whitespace from start and end of the row:
   $row=trim($row);
   $id=$row[0];
   $name=$row[1];
   $address=$row[2];
   $email=$row[3];
   $date=$row[4];
   mysql_query("UPDATE TABLE SET name='$name',....);
}
?>
```

Comment: Would there also be a where clause?

Answer (score 1):

PHP has a function called [fgetcsv()](http://is.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) to parse CSV files.

You could use that to loop through your CSV file and create MySQL update strings. Which you could execute either through mysql_query() or just to copy and paste into the Query window in PHPMyAdmin.