# How to update a column in mySQL database with Excel

Tags: php, mysql, database, excel, phpmyadmin

I have a table which has approx. 10,000 client records.
The table structure look like this:

**ClientID** | **FirstName** | **LastName** | **PhoneNumber**

I am trying to update the **PhoneNumber** column with a updated Excel file, 
which only has two columns, **ClientID** | **PhoneNumber**

My cpanel has phpmyadmin installed, but how do I import the excel file into the database and only update the **PhoneNumber** based on **ClientID**?

Thank all!

Comment: Is this a once off solution? If so then @octern's approach is a good one. If not you can connect to your SQL DB directly from excel using ADO in VBA

Comment: @Dan it could be good if you make an answer for your approach.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How i can import a file(csv/excel) with partial data to table in database through phpmyadmin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/781127/how-i-can-import-a-filecsv-excel-with-partial-data-to-table-in-database-throug)

Answer (score 7):

I don't know if that's possible, but you can easily use the excel spreadsheet to generate a series of MySQL commands to update the phone number. If the ID is column A and the phone number is column B, then the function would just be:

`concatenate("update yourTableName set phonenumber = '", A1, "' where ID = ", B1, ";")`

Then fill down and copy the resulting commands into PHPMyAdmin's SQL tab.

Answer (score 6):

**Simple, tricky, and clever solution:**

Copy it do datasheet with Columns:

```
SQL | PhoneNumber | SQL | ClientID | SQL
```

**Sample data:**

Column 1: `UPDATE clients SET phonenumber = '` (copy it to every row)

Column 2: `12345`

Column 3: `' WHERE  ClientID=` (copy it to every row)

Column 4: `123`

Column 5: `;` (copy it to every row)

**Save it as CSV (space separated, without quotes), import as SQL**

Comment: Wouldn't that sql file contain a lot of extraneous commas (or tabs, etc)?

Comment: To be honest i don't what about excel, but in OpenOffice you can save CSV without quotes, and use space as separator. Anyway it's not a problem to remove quotes from file in text editor.

Comment: I don't believe excel makes that option available normally. Anyway, even if the delimiter were a space, it would still mess with things. e.g., if phonenumber is being handled as a string, it will save it as " 555-5555 " instead of "555-5555".

Comment: it's not a problem to replace all `" "` occurencies in text editor to ` `. Converting, replacing, and importing is work for 2-3 minutes :)

Comment: Perfect trick!  Amazing solution.