# Update a MYSQL Table with an EXCEL

Tags: mysql, excel

I have a mysql database with tables in it. I am currently able to export the data from this table into an Excel file using phpmyadmin. I modify it in Ms Excel and save it. 
Now, I want to reimport it and update the table with the modification done on the data without having to drop/empty the table and reimport.
How can I achieve this ?
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update a column in mySQL database with Excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12081716/how-to-update-a-column-in-mysql-database-with-excel)

Comment: Export your file in .csv format and then follow the link below http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21495600/import-csv-to-update-rows-in-table